# 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, .net-6.0

All,

I am getting the following exception when I try call my web api (.net 6) end point using postman (I tried content type: form-data/application/x-www-form-urlencoded and I did include user, pwd parameters in the body, post url: http://localhost:5000/api/auth):

```
  {StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2022 18:12:40 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}}
```

Here's my web api controller:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("/api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;

        public AuthController(ILogger<AuthController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost()]
        public string GetToken([FromBody] AuthCredentials cred)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(AuthController)} => Received user: {cred.User}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(AuthController)} => Received pwd: {cred.Pwd}");
            return "token:12345";
        }
    }
```

It worked before, when I was passing user/pwd as separate fields, the minute I put [FromBody] it stopped working and I started getting this exception.

```
public class AuthCredentials
    {
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }
    }
```

I do use SignalR + Webapis, here's my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers(); // only for web api controllers

            services.AddSignalR()
                .AddHubOptions<ServerHub>(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null; // null is unlimited
                })
                // add message pack, requires nuget: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack (you must be on .net6 to use this nuget)
                .AddMessagePackProtocol(); 
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Running SignalR hub, at url: /server");
                });

                endpoints.MapHub<ServerHub>("/server", options =>
                {
                    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
                
                });

                endpoints.MapControllers(); // only for api controllers

            });
        }
    }
```

**

- UPDATE: Fixed the Unsupported Media Type

**
I was able to fix the Unsupported Media Type exception by changing this line and adding form data content-type:

```
services
                .AddControllers(options =>
                {
                    var jsonInputFormatter = options.InputFormatters
                        .OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>()
                        .Single();
                    jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
                        .Add("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                });
```

But now, when I run post man I get 400, bad request exception:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-46970e65eec389a5d6d355d960823e57-dd8db1776ac7f90c-00",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
        ]
    }
}
```

Q:
How can I pass in using form Data (user, pwd), and populate AuthCredentials object on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you trying to call this action from postman

```
 [HttpPost()]
public string GetToken([FromBody] AuthCredentials cred)

 _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(AuthController)} => Received user: {cred.User}");
 _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(AuthController)} => Received pwd: {cred.Pwd}");
 return "token:12345";
}
```

you need to select body=>raw=>json options in postmant and add your data as

```
{
  "user": "user",
  "pwd" : "pwd"
}
```

and  remove all extra code you added to AddController config. It is only confusing and probably will cause more problems in the future

Comment: That worked, thanks. I was hopping I could use FormBody attribute in conjunction with form-data and the pipeline would populate my AuthCredentials type from posted body. Btw, this setup that I was trying to use works with api controllers in asp.net framework, looks like .net core doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's doesn't work, is that you are trying to retrieve parameter from the URL, but you are using **[FromBody]** which is supposed to use the body of your request to send parameters .

Try to send your parameters as shown below

[image]